# How to access company name from calculate_shipping in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

We need to access the **company name** from the checkout form in WooCommerce, inside the `calculate_shipping` (from [Shipping Method API](https://woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/#section-5)) when calculating the shipping options, but it only seems to have the array `$package` available which in turn just have access to a stripped down version of the `$package['destination']` address fields. There is no `$package['destination']['company']`.

[The company name form field in checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyKcP.png)

As part of the **Billing address**;

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_company" id="billing_company" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="organization">
```

As part of the **Shipping address**;

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="shipping_company" id="shipping_company" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="organization">
```

Is there a way to directly access what is entered into the **"shipping_company"** or **"billing_company"** textfields or by any other means know if the customer is a company or private person?

I've tried `WC()->checkout->get_value( 'shipping_company' )` but that doesn't return the text and there is no `$_POST['shipping_company']` or `$_POST['billing_company']` despite the **AJAX** hook when changing address details.

Comment: Much better. (except that the link seems to points to a code for creating a custom plugin, for extension.. and not to the WooCommerce default source code). Can you also tell once you know this company name, what the ultimate intention is with the shipping options?

Comment: @7uc1f3r Yes, calculate_shipping is part of WooCommerce's own Shipping Method API that is used for customized shipping calculations. And since different shipping services are delievered to business addresses and residential addresses, knowing whether the recipient is a company or a private person is rather crucial to provide correct shipping options.